DAX to compare 2 values and return text
I am using a text box to describe changes to a business model when certain changes are made, however I cannot seem to find the correct way to compare 2 x values to give me a result.   I get an error saying comparing true/false with type text (the values are currency, same decimal etc), the error suggests using format or value, neither seems to work.
Originally
V_^SalesAction =
switch (
[^GrossSales$] > [GrossSales$], "Increase",
[^GrossSales$] < [GrossSales$], "Reduce",
"Maintain"
)
Also tried, many variations of this, applying value to the leading or trailing number. Same with format.
V_^SalesAction =
switch (
value([^GrossSales$]) > value([GrossSales$]), "Increase",
value([^GrossSales$]) < value([GrossSales$]), "Reduce",
"Maintain"
)
I would like to see the variable "V_^SaleAction, change depending on the new GrossSales value (the delta) when compared with the original GrossSales value.

Try adding true.
V_^SalesAction =
switch ( TRUE, 
[^GrossSales$] > [GrossSales$], "Increase",
[^GrossSales$] < [GrossSales$], "Reduce",
"Maintain"
)

